# Why use printf %f for print 100.00100 results 100.000999?

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float c = 100.001000;
    printf("%f\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

But result is:

```
100.000999
```

Why this happen? Where is rule for this result in C standards?

Comment: In binary floating point, there's no such number as exactly 100.001.  (Just as in decimal floating point, there's no such number as exactly 1/3.)

Comment: As the constant `100.001000` is not exactly representable as a `double`, the closest alternative is used `100.00100000000000477...`.  Yet this `double` constant fails to store exactly as a `float`.  The closest is `100.00099945068359375` which when printed to 6 places after the `.` rounds , as text,  to  `100.000999`